# Should questions about official documentation be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Does/should the "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic" rule include questions asking us to locate something within the relevant official documentation?  I don't think it should - assuming of course that the documentation is big enough and/or hard enough to search that this isn't something the OP should have been able to do without assistance.

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484117/where-is-it-written-that-applications-should-not-write-to-c-program-files) which has been closed on those grounds; technically I suppose MSDN is an off-site resource - on the other hand, he isn't asking us to find MSDN but to find something within MSDN.  A technicality perhaps - but it's a good question, IMO, which is likely to be helpful to other people.

Thoughts?

Comment: Nothing about that question is limiting it to MSDN.  The entire internet (and even beyond the internet) is in scope in that question.

Comment: @Servy: I read it as asking for something official from Microsoft, which in this context more or less means MSDN.

Comment: Microsoft make official statements in all sorts of contexts beyond MSDN.

Comment: I don't see how that question is about official documentation. I agree with closing as it's looking for an off-site resource, not an answer to a question/problem.

Comment: @Servy: technical statements related to development?

Comment: @KevinB: I don't see how else it could be answered?  Anything not officially from MS is just speculation, not "where the rule is written".

Comment: @HarryJohnston The question does *not* state, "where is the rule written *by Microsoft*", it simply says, "where is the rule written".  It's asking for where *anyone* has given that guideline.  Nothing is out of scope.

Comment: Whether or not it's looking for official or non-official isn't the grounds that i'm basing my close decision off of anyway.

Comment: The question likely could have been worded in a better way that didn't just ask for where the rule is written, but to rather explain why the rule exists. Then, a brief explanation could be given with a reference to the official documentation.

Comment: Meh, what this guy really wants is "prove it to me, Microsoft."

Comment: @KevinB: personally, I'd close such a question as opinion-based. :-)

Comment: Is it an opinion though? or is there a real reason that rule exists? is it a real rule? (i don't know, maybe someone in that field does) but, i would agree with a primarily opinion based vote, it's similar to asking why the DOM api doesn't have an event listener list.

Comment: @KevinB: yes, it's a real rule, at least for some definition of rule; the answer given points to the relevant MS documentation.

Comment: hmm... re-reading that close reason, brings up a good point... *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."* In this particular case, it wouldn't attract opinionated answers and spam because it's an officially documented piece of information. However, it still clearly falls under that close reason.

Comment: @Servy: a matter of interpretation I suppose.  My reasoning, for the record: anyone can write a guideline or a recommendation about how to write Windows software, but only Microsoft can write a *rule*.   (Obviously, I'm excluding certain specialized contexts such as where the software requires certification against some third-party standard.)  That may be too much weight to put on a single word, though IMO the rest of the question supports my interpretation.

Comment: It doesn't strike me as any worse than any of the plethora of questions/answers discussing and referring to the C++ standard.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The difference is that in those questions one is asking whether something is or is not allowed in the standard, whether something compiles with the standard, etc.  Someone is actually asking for the answer to their question, in those cases.  This question is not asking for an answer, it's asking for a link to an answer that is somewhere else.  If it were actually asking for an answer to the question, rather than where he can find the answer, then the given close reason would not apply.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

OK, to summarize: it's not unanimous, but there's clearly a majority consensus that questions about official documentation are not desirable on Stack Overflow, even if useful.

Answer (score 8):

"Where do I find the documentation for X?" sounds like an inherently poor question.  If you don't understand something about X then ask us about X.  Perhaps you'll get an answer, perhaps you'll get a link to the documentation (with an appropriate quote, etc.), or perhaps you'll get a link to some 3rd party (again, with an appropriate quote).  If the topic is too broad, then that's the problem with the post.  If you don't know *what* you're confused about, or what you don't understand, then clearly your question isn't specific enough to ask on SO.

Comment: So you would, or would not close these questions?  Which close reason would you use?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would think that the close reason used here is probably the most applicable.  It's asking people to provide a link to something that answers their question, instead of just asking for an answer to their question.  The solution, as with pretty much every single question closed with this close reason, is to simply edit the question to ask for what the person actually wants, instead of asking for a link to something that gives them what they want (Unless doing so would make the question "too broad", in which case, they're SOL).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  Does the user want enlightenment, or just a pointer to enlightenment elsewhere?  The former, fine.  The latter, close as "icanhazlinkz" or edit to suit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't see it.  The OP in this case at least doesn't need enlightenment, he already knows the answer - but needs to prove it to his boss, or his colleagues.  (Or perhaps, admittedly, to some random person on the internet.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah, that's not why we're here.  We close "convince my boss" questions on Programmers on a regular basis.  See also http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/how-do-i-explain-something-to-someone

Comment: @RobertHarvey: not *quite* the same thing; personally, I agree that questions about explaining or demonstrating something technical to non-technical people should be off topic, but I'd prefer to allow questions about demonstrating something technical to other technical people.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That's a pretty fine line.  Historically, hashing out such gray areas on meta has been the source of much wailing and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: The documentation for X normally doesn't only contain X; it lists other topics, A, B, ..Y, Z.  So if we can ask "How do I use A", "How do I use B", "How do I use X", why don't you accept a single question "Where's the documentation for X"?