# RTFM, but don't ask us where TFM is

Tags: discussion, scope

My current understanding is that we'd prefer users to read documentation before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

And yet, questions about where to find documentation are apparently off-topic on Stack Overflow. ([Recent question about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253777/should-questions-about-official-documentation-be-on-topic/255086#255086))

Why are we banning questions that enable them to do something that we want them to do? This seems rather contradictory to me.

Comment: What that question shows is _hardly_ a consensus, if anything, it shows people don't feel strongly about it either way. The aim of Stack Overflow is often to _be_ the non-existing documentation a lot of languages/libraries/frameworks don't have.

Comment: Also, it's perfectly acceptable to expect OP would google "PHP Manual" and click the first link to reach the PHP manual, for example.

Comment: When the documentation is hard to find, I think the community is a bit more forgiving, assuming the OP has given the impression he has tried to find it.  But when the answer is easily found on MSDN by Googling the name of the class, the community will generally react negatively.

Comment: @psubsee2003 is exactly right. The Android documentation, for example, isn't always the most clear on certain things. So if a user shows that they have searched in the documentation for something but still can't find it or is having trouble then we generally will lend a helping hand.

Comment: There are many things we expect (research, code examples, spelling, general coherence), but at the same time we don't consider questions specifically about those on-topic. I think it's OK to demand some prerequisites without offering to teach those from scratch.

Comment: Why would we even want to help the kind of people who come to SO with technical questions before they have even located the manual? You'll only encourage them to stay.

Answer (score 14):

It's not that we want people to read documentation (we do, but that's not the main issue).

We want people to actually make some effort on their question, Google, read documentation, give it a try themselves, before asking.

"Reading documentation" is a fancier phrasing to "google it", because most (if not all) documentation on a language/project is found on Google very easily.

So if a person can't bother doing the most basic Google search and on many cases, even form coherent English sentences in their question, we'd close it, yes.

---

Also, for most languages and projects, the links to the documentation are found rather early on the tag wiki (although not many people even know it exists). Example, [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).