# Is this question acceptable or off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/32099803. I know that it is off topic to ask for libraries or other off site resources, but here OP says what he wants to use (spring), shows he already found spring.io site, and asks whether pdf versions exists.

They used to be explicitely accessible from main site, but are now partially hidden, so I can understand that a new user cannot find them.

On the other hand, the question got rapidly 2 downvotes what let think that some members found it bad for SO...

Precision after @Stijn answer: OP does not ask to *recommend* an off-site resource. It just ask *how to find* so the risk for opinion only answer seems lower.

Comment: Assuming there are no PDFs of the Spring documentation on stackoverflow.com, it's still an off-site resource...

Comment: Googling "spring pdf documentation" ...  Well, they did at pretty crummy job at hiding it.  Don't feed the vampires.

Comment: How is *"how to find"* this specific thing different to how to find anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to argue that since OP put in some effort, the question should be allowed. The off-topic rule is very simple:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [...]

So no, it's not acceptable and it should be closed.

Comment: My question is precisely on the *recommend* which is **not** on the question. I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Serge *recommend or find*

Comment: Ok, I think this is the general advice. I've even just found [this answer from Servy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253779) to a similar question.

Answer (score -4):

There are multiple sides to this.

First, the issue is that they're asking for an off-site resource.  Admittedly, [a few hits](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spring%20pdf%20documentation) [on Google pull up](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spring+epub+documentation) [*exactly* what they](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spring+single+page+html+documentation) are looking for, so there's very little effort in this question.  That certainly doesn't help the "research" aspect of the question.

The lettering of the rule that this was closed under, emphasis mine, states that this isn't permissible here.

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Now, to the second point here.  I feel like I actually *gained* knowledge from this question, since I wasn't even aware that an ePub version of the Spring documentation even *existed*.  I'll be adding that to my library soon.

The main reason that the rule above exists is so that we don't get a whole bunch of, "Plz recommend tutorial" or "Plz recommend book" sort of questions here.  In this case, it's a, "Where can I find an offline copy of a programming API that I use?"

The question *seems* fair to me because:

- It's a specific framework's documentation (Spring)
- It's looking for a specific thing (offline version)
- It's definitely useful for others (not everyone wants to pay for WiFi on a plane/train)

Of course, because they include the getting started guides in this, that makes it an easy close target. If that were edited out, I wouldn't have that many problems with this question.

All in all, I'm hoping that this gives you a bit more clairvoyance into why it was closed.  My hope is that it could be a question that can be accepted - perhaps after judicious editing and a wiki lock.

Comment: Do we really want an answer that we need to maintain in case the links break?

Comment: If this were a specific hard-coded version number, I could totally see your point.  However, `current` points to the most up-to-date version of the documentation that the *very Spring site uses*, so I have little fear of the link breaking.

Comment: It depends on the site - MSDN links are known to break spectacularly all the time regardless of versioning.

Comment: @Makoto: thank you for your support :-) . But I'm afraid the general advice is that SO has not to provide links to external documentation...